# Loading only 2 records from file into target table for every run using Informatica

Tags: informatica

I have a source file which contains 10 records.
It doesn't has any primary key. 
Requirement is to load first two records at first run into target table. And then delete those records from source file. 
Now the source file will have 8 records.  In next run, first 2 records will get loaded into target followed by getting deleted from source file.. 
How can I achieve this in Informatica Power centre

Answer (score 0):

Use a sequence generator and a filter transformation to load only first two records. For deleting those records use scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Source -> Sequence Generator -> Router(Group1 - Seq <=2 || Group 2 - Seq >2 )

You can now have two write components connected to each group of the router. 1st write component would be the target file and the other would be your source file where append if exists property is not enabled.

Comment: How can I have a same source flat file as source and target..  Couod you please explain me how can I implement this